# How to replace Greek letters from mathptmx with mtpro2 lite?

Tags: greek, mtpro, mathptmx

The Greek letters from `mathptmx` are horrible, some are even identical when they shouldn't be (rho and varrho for example). I'm new to `LaTeX`, so as simple as this task may be, I cannot figure it out. I want to replace all the small Greek letters from `mathptmx` with the ones you get from `mtpro2`, the Lite version (except for pi), as well as the infinity-sign.

Thank you, in advance :)

Comment: Welcome! It is not simple to do this. If you could post a minimal document, that would be good. So would a link the the lite version of the fonts. (I don't know if these are free, but the link will help if so.)

Comment: That said, I would really recommend trying to find a ready-made solution which you like. There are other options out there and it will be much, much easier and likely much more satisfactory in terms of results to use one of those. `mathptmx` is not, after all, the only gave in town.

Comment: Is there a reason for not simply (a) not loading the `mathptmx` package and (b) loading the `times` and `mtpro2` packages instead? (Instead of loading the `times` package, you could also issue the directive `\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}`.)  Why stop at the lowercase Greek letters? For instance, the `\sum` and `\int` symbols provided by `mtpro2` are way better than the ones from `mathptmx`.

Comment: Well, the full `mtpro2` has a price of $129 (academic). The Lite version has many limitations, and it does not work nearly as well when it comes to chemistry, or chemistry-related packages. I'm basically trying to get everything as I want it, without having to pay anything. I have already replaced the `\sum`, manipulated the `\int`, and lots of other things to my liking. The only thing remaining, really, are the lowercase Greek letters. The free `mtpro2` lite version does provide those.

Comment: @Mico Well, `times.sty` is deprecated. However, it isn't as though there aren't other options for Times-like configurations. @ OP ***Especially*** if you are already making changes of the kind you describe, you really should post a minimal example so we can reproduce your current font configuration. And, as I say, a link would be good. I've got a full installation of TeX Live. I have zero idea where the fonts you are referring to are. Sure, I could look it up. But, heck, I'd also have to create a document, hoping it is sufficiently similar to yours.... Life's too short.

Comment: But, really, I'd again urge you to consider the alternatives. Mishmashes never work out as well as you hope.